# Error when calling getItem method of external model

Tags: component, development, model

I'm using a model of other component in my component. I'm following this [solution](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/189/how-can-i-use-a-model-of-other-component-in-my-component). But, when I try to call the `getItem` method of the model I get the error "Call to a member function load() on a non-object". In the model, the lines that cause the error is:

```
    ...
    $table = $this->getTable();

    // Attempt to load the row.
    $return = $table->load($itemId);
    ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hard to really guide without more code.  However, I'd start with doing a var_dump($table); before attempting to load the row to see what's being returned, and if it isn't an instance of the table class you're requesting, step through the getTable() method to see what params are being supplied to it, what it's trying to load, and where it's failing.

Comment: @Michael the `var_dump` returns `bool(false)`. The model belongs to other component, so it is trying to load a table from that component. Take a look at the link above to see how I'm importing the model.

Comment: And the getTable() should theoretically work also.  You may need to call JTable::addIncludePath(/path/to/other/component/tables); to ensure that component's table classes are getting loaded.

Comment: Yeah! The `JTable::addIncludePath` works. Thanks

Comment: Moving my last comment over as an answer, if you could help out with the beta and mark that as accepted it'd be appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to import the table classes also.  Try calling `JTable::addIncludePath(/path/to/other/component/tables);` to bring them in.